# How to convert a xml file to json string and back keeping attributes

Tags: java, xml, json, org.json

I'm trying to convert a xml file to json and backwards, but when doing so the integrity changes, from:

`<option value="0">
  <!--something-->
</option>`

to

`<option>
  <!--something-->
  <value>0</value>
</option>`

I get this when using org.json, is there another json library that can do this job while keeping file integrity?

Comment: Since JSON does not have the notion of attributes, this sounds complicated. How would the JSON to XML conversion know what JSON property should be converted to an XML attribute and which one should be converted to an XML element ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library with static method `U.xmlToJson(xml)`.

```
<option value="0">
  <!--something-->
</option>
```

Output:

```
{
  "option": {
    "-value": "0",
    "#comment": "something"
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```

Comment: Indeed this should be the accepted answer. json.org's JSON library transforms xml attributes to nodes, and Jackson's implementation doesn't handle mixed content. This library resolved both for me. Good work!

Answer (score -3):

**XML to Json**

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject; 
import org.json.JSONObject;.  

    public class Main {

            public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
            public static String TEST_XML_STRING ="ur xml";

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                    JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
                    String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
                    System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
                } catch (JSONException je) {
                    System.out.println(je.toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

json to xml :

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class jsontoxml {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
    String str="ur json here";  
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        String xml = XML.toString(json);
            System.out.println(xml);            
    }

}
```